# using jsonp with ajax HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I have a simple html page that I open directly, file://abc.html

It has the following code

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/ajax_info.php",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

ajax_info.php has echo 'hello' only in it.

On each reload the **Network** tab in chrome shows that a request is made to

```
http://localhost:8080/ajax_info.php?jsoncallback=jQuery1111016803214247142373_1471278920224&_=1471278920236
```

and hello as a response is received but I dont get the alert box.

When I execute the page it shows nothing (no alert box), I am supposed to get alert with hello in it, Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: _"ajax_info.php has echo 'hello' only in it."_ - That's not how jsonp works..

Comment: @JasonP what should it have, I am just making PoC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this function to yours:

```
function jsoncallback(json){
 alert(json);
}
```

EDIT: and when you want to use JSONP the server should echo params in the function you want:

do this on server

```
echo 'jsoncallback("hello!")';
```

or this:

```
echo 'jsoncallback('. json_encode($some_data) .')';
```

Of course 'jsoncallback' is the name of user function, that any user may want to change, so you have to do it right way:

```
echo $user_sent_me_this_name . '(' . json_encode($some_data) . ')';
```

Comment: I have tried that , it says Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined

Comment: I've added explanation what server should do. Basically server should echo _working javascript_

Comment: you really really need jsonP? it's for cross domain ajax requests only.

Comment: Yes I have a file:// html file making request to cross domain LAN web server, thanks this helps.

Comment: If you control backend it's cheaper to use CORS. Cople minutes in nginx settings and you are done. Nobody already uses jsonP because it's ugly and hacky and you have to write different templates for regular request and jsonP requests....

Answer (score 0):

```
 success: function(data) {alert(data);}
```

This code is fine , make sure that your Ajax connection is working.
to know that you can use `error:` parameter.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/ajax_info.php",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function() {
             $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
          }
    });
```

Comment: actually I need to edit the php as the first answer mentioned, it should return, FUNCTIONNAME('DATA_I_WANT_TO_RETURN);